# send_headers don't work on wordpress multisite

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, headers

I have written a simple plugin to send some security http headers. I've tested it on various wordpress installations but on a wordpress multisite network it seems that the headers are not sended. The plugin is active for the entire network and in the `.htaccess` file there is no instruction to set the headers. Is there any error with my code?

```
<?php

if(! defined('WPINC') ){
  die;
}

class WP_Security_Headers{

  public function init(){
    add_action('send_headers', array($this, 'set_http_headers'));
  }

  private function set_http_headers(){
    header("Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
    header("Set-Cookie: HttpOnly;Secure");
    header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com; font-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'; frame-src https://www.google.com; ");
    header("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN");
    header("X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block");
    header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
    header("Referrer-Policy: strict-origin");
    header("X-Pingback: ");
    header("X-Powered-By: ");
  }

}

$wp_s = new WP_Security_Headers;
$wp_s->init();

?>
```

Comment: "Just to note that `send_headers` does not work to beat page caching used by plugins such as W3 Total Cache in my tests, or any static caching that effectively bypasses WordPress at the server level." from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213988/wp-headers-vs-send-headers-when-to-use-each – So, maybe cache?

Comment: I'm not using any caching plugin.

Comment: There is no error in your code as far as I am concerned. May be syntax errors can trouble you a lot in your coding.